# VPN, routing, specified application

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, routing

Details:

eth0 = current internet port

pptp1 = VPN connection, when I connect to my provider, the provider gives me an IP address, which is accessible from the internet. I would like to connect through this IP back to my PC.

I want to keep my primary internet connection (eth0) on my PC for all traffic, but route traffic through the VPN for a specified application/or port, to access application/port from the IP, which I given from the pptp provider. Huhh? Difficult but, it is possible? If yes, how?

The incoming port will be always: 33340 Outgoing port can be change, but usually it is 33330

Comment: This a Linux desktop and it's acting as your Internet gateway? more details.

Answer (score 1):

You should read [Linux Advanced Routing and Traffic Control HOWTO](http://lartc.org/lartc.html).

In short: there are several routing tables. `route` utility manages only one of them - main, to view/modify other tables you should use `ip`. If you want to use different routes for some traffic, you should create custom table, define ruotes in it and create rules to pass your traffic though that table. Rules may use mark, set to some packets by iptables target MARK.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this guide to setup specific routes before. It should be a light read/process.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-configure-pptp-vpn-in-ubuntu-intrepid-and-jaunty.html

Comment: Please consider avoiding just linking to other sites, instead providing specific details in your answer. It's no use someone coming back to this site a year from now to find that your link has 404'd (or similar).